# Tensorflow V2.1.0 and Numpy compatibility

Tags: numpy, tensorflow2.0

I installed tensorflow v2.1.0. The Jupyter notebook on my Mac showed lots of warnings already when I just imported tensorflow. See the screenshot below:

[image]

How do I fix the compatibility issue?

Comment: which version of numpy and tensorflow are you using?

Comment: The numpy version is 1.18.1.